# What is the set represented by [n]

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

While reading the paper "On Span Programs" by Karchmer and Wigderson (1993) I have come across the following definition:
[image]

The highlighted part of the definition contains the following elements that I find confusing:

1. What is the set represented by $[n]$? Is it the set of all of the natural numbers between 1 (or 0) and N?
2. What does $\epsilon = 0, 1$ mean? Does this mean that $\epsilon$ can be either 0 or 1? If so, shouldn't it be $\epsilon \in \{0,1\}$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for both questions. We have $[n] = \mathbb Z \cap [1,n]$.  You’re right that $\epsilon \in \{0,1\}$ is probably better way to write this, but maybe the authors thought it looked clumsy since the notation was already inside a set.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, $[n] := \{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Here, $\epsilon = 0, 1$ indicates $\epsilon \in \{0,1\}$, but it's been abbreviated to avoid extra curly braces.

By analogy, $x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ indicates $x \in \{\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a},\frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\}$, but it's much neater to write it the first way.

Comment: I think the best notation would be $x \boldsymbol{\in} \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$. This emphasizes the set of two values, a frequent point of confusion for students. Ah well, you can't really disagree with established convention.

Answer (score 0):

There are alternating views as to whether $[n]$ should refer to $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ or whether $[n]$ should refer to $\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$, similarly to how some people prefer that $\Bbb N$ includes zero while others prefer it does not include zero.

In either case, $[n]$ is the prototypical $n$-element set using the first consecutive $n$ natural numbers.  In most scenarios it does not even matter which of the two sets are actually being intended since the point is for the set to be a set with $n$ elements and it doesn't actually matter what those $n$ elements really are and there is an obvious bijection between $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ and $\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$.

Comment: I agree there could be alternating views and there is of course no "objective" answer, but by far the vast majority of texts I have encountered use $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ (i.e. not including $0$). Is that different in your experience?